# ImportError: No module named unable to import toplevel directory of module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Directory structure:

```
├── common
│   ├── common.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── project1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts
│       ├── example_import.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── project2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── scripts
        └── __init__.py
```

I need to import common/common.py module in project1/scripts/example_import.py file

example_import.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../common")
from common import Test
print("Module Not import error")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1/scripts/example_import.py", line 3, in <module>
    from common import Test
ImportError: No module named common
```

How to fix a issue?

Comment: Try to replace your sys.path.append with this one:  `sys.path.append( os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/..') )`

Comment: No Luck, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding how Python imports work is tricky in the beginning but makes sense once you understand how.

There are different way to fix your import issue. I would not recommend messing up with `sys.path`. Depending on where you are calling your script, you have multiple choice at hand.

Your Directory structure.

```
├── common
│   ├── common.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── project1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts
│       ├── example_import.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── project2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── scripts
        └── __init__.py
```

On the root of directory

```py
python project1/scripts/example_import.py
```

Will work, assuming that the imports in example_import.py looks like

```py
from common.common import Test
```

If you want to use `from common import Test`, you need to add  `from common.common import Test` in `__init__.py` file in common folder.

You can also use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to tell Python where to look for the base module.

```sh
PYTHONPATH=/pathto/basefolder python folder/filesx.py
```

Another way is to create a `setup.py` on base and do development installation `python -m pip install --editable .`  on environment you are working on.

Example of `setup.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='projectX',
      version='1.0',
      description='The World is not Enoug',
      author='James Bond',
      author_email='agent@007.net',
      url='https://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['common', 'project1', 'project2],
     )
```

See [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) for more setup.py options.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, still from common.common import Test, not working for me. I am running in parent directory

Comment: Can you try `PYTHONPATH=. python project1/scripts/example_import.py`

Comment: This works, anyway we can avoid using PYTHONPATH=.?

Comment: Can you add this line on top of your file `import sys;print(sys.path)`, so we can see where Python is searching your paths?

Comment: That is because we told Python our base directory. You can avoid it by installing the editable using setup.py

Comment: [root@test-server py_module_test]# PYTHONPATH=. python3 project1/scripts/example_import.py
['/root/py_module_test/project1/scripts', '/root/py_module_test', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
working now

Comment: [root@test-server py_module_test]# python3 project1/scripts/example_import.py
['/root/py_module_test/project1/scripts', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1/scripts/example_import.py", line 2, in <module>
    from common.common import Test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'